# Instead of using -www-form-urlencoded, I want to use application/json in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Instead of using -www-form-urlencoded, I want to use application/json. the value of username and password becomes null. I found on the net that .net core by default accepts json. Why is it not working in my case?

The basic project was created using `yo aspnet`.

I have implemented the code as shown in the blog https://goblincoding.com/2016/07/03/issuing-and-authenticating-jwt-tokens-in-asp-net-core-webapi-part-i/#comment-1446

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Actually I was using `[FromForm]` attribute for action method parameters. I replaced it with `[FromBody]`. It is working.